# Notification is not closing with app android?

Tags: android, notifications, exit

I followed [RadioPlayerService](https://github.com/iammert/RadioPlayerService/blob/master/app/src/main/java/co/mobiwise/myapplication/RadioActivity.java) as a example to Create radio stream in android

I have added the below code to exit in ***RadioActivity.java***

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit ! Radio App.");
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Click Yes to Exit!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                moveTaskToBack(true);
                                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                                System.exit(0);

                            }
                        })

                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }
```

Here My app is exiting but the notification is working [this](https://github.com/iammert/RadioPlayerService/blob/master/library/src/main/java/co/mobiwise/library/radio/RadioPlayerService.java) is my notification class

Can any one suggest me How to kill entire app on exit

Or combine both notification service and main activity so that I can exit the app completely

[This](https://github.com/iammert/RadioPlayerService) is the full reference code

Can any one suggest me on this kind

**Update 1**

I am giving exit option in main activity not in other service
my main activity is `RadioActivity.java` and my service is `RadioPlayerService.java`

So here I am giving Exit to main activity so I what i need means instead of exiting main activity It should exit entire app including service.

Don't down-vote without comment don't comment without seeing full sourcode ..

Thanks again

Comment: do you mean , when you go back from your activity you want to clear all the notification and stop playing ?

Comment: yes in other words its exit or force close notification when app is exited or closed

Comment: `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                                System.exit(0);` is not good way to close activity

Comment: ok @MaňishYadav can you suggest me how to exit entire app including notification

Comment: @Don'tBenegative check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122399/exit-entire-app-at-once)

Comment: thanks Manish Yadav your code worked noice but media player is not closed but after adding this its exited every thing mRadioManager .disconnect();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `System.exit(0);` , I would like suggest you not to use it. It is not a good programming style to use it. There is a method called `finish();`

- You don't need to call `System.exit(0)` to terminate an `Activity`, just `Activity.finish()`

## Close an application

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(homeIntent);
```

---

You can make your activity as Single instance so that from anywhere you call the device will return the same activity from the stack.

In Manifest.xml

" ...  android:launchMode="singleInstance">

To avoid an `Intent` to call multiple instance of the same `Activity` remove the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag from the `Intent` and add the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` one.

From Doc:

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
>   If set, and the activity being launched is
>   already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new
>   instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it
>   will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top)
>   old activity as a new Intent.
>
> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>   If set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this history stack.

---

## Clear all notification

```
NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nMgr.cancelAll();
```

## Update1

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit ! Radio App.");
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click Yes to Exit!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            mRadioManager .disconnect();// after adding this its also closed radio player
                            NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                            nMgr.cancelAll();
                            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                            homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
                            homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(homeIntent);

                        }
                    })

            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

Comment: actually I am giving exit option to main activity itself radioactivty.java can you update your answer

Comment: @Don'tBenegative pls check the complete solution I have updated this may help. if u still have prb then comment here :-) #soReadyToHelp *don't downvote please*

Comment: thanks @Manish Yadav sir...... your code worked nice but radio player is not closed but after adding this its exited every thing mRadioManager .disconnect();

Answer (score 1):

so basically what you can do is, when you click yes on your dialog, you should kill your activity by calling finish(), and also you have to stop your service, or if it is binded by your Activity, you can avoid calling stopService and it will automatically unbind when your activity is destroyed by calling Finish(), check the code below

```
   AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit ! Radio App.");
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Click Yes to Exit!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                moveTaskToBack(true);
                                //this will unbind the radioService
                                mRadioManager.disconnect();
                                finish();

                            }
                        })

                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

and in your **RadioPlayerService** , override **onDestroy** method and call the public method **stopFromNotification**() method also

Comment: Here what is your_service_action in intent My notification is [this](https://github.com/iammert/RadioPlayerService/blob/master/library/src/main/java/co/mobiwise/library/radio/RadioPlayerService.java) can you update your answer

Comment: @Don'tBenegative can you tell me in your RadioActivity, how you are starting your RadioService or can you paste the link of your RadioActivity. i will update accordingly :)

Comment: Please see the entire code that radio service is in library but in my code I combined both see full source code and upvote dont downvote plese without refering

Comment: @Don'tBenegative please check my answer, i have updated the code after reviewing your code shared , and i don't downvote on any post, don't worry :)

Comment: @Don'tBenegative also override onDestroy in your RadioService class and call stopFromNotification method, this will fix everything

Comment: thanks @Hasif Seyd sir In your answer this (`mRadioManager.disconnect();
                                finish();`) helped me lo lot